# Using ImageMagick to resize images from command line in PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick to generate a small thumbnail of images. `convert --version` shows  `ImageMagick 4.2.9 99/09/01`.

```
$output = array();

$cmd = "/opt/RZmagick4/bin/convert data/test.jpg data/small.png"; // works fine
$cmd = "/opt/RZmagick4/bin/convert data/test.jpg -resize 300x200 data/small.jpg"; // does not work

exec($cmd, $output);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Why does the second `$cmd` not work? Output for both is `Array( )`. However, there is just no output image.

Comment: You might have a reason for not using Imagick, but in case you weren't  aware of it, PHP has a built in library called Imagick that acts as an API for image magick. Check it out, it's better: http://www.php.net/imagick

Comment: What happens if you run the command directly from the command line? Note that the first command writes a PNG file and the second a JPG. Is that intended?

Comment: ImageMagick 4??? Stone Age! ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-10-26

Answer (score 3):

You should write this:

```
$cmd = "/opt/RZmagick4/bin/convert -resize 300x200 data/test.jpg data/small.jpg";
```